# How to keep a grid column from repeating the same data

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1

I am developing an application using ExtJS, and in one of my models I have field which is an array type, how can I set a `dataIndex` in grid so the data does not repeat when I edit one cell?

My code is shown below.

[image]

```
{
        xtype: 'button',
        icon : Webapp.icon('add1.png'),
        iconAlign : 'top',
        handler : function() {  
            var gridView = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('gridpanel')[1];
            grid = gridView.headerCt;
            if(grid.getGridColumns().length >= 1){
                var column = Ext.create('Ext.grid.column.Column', { dataIndex: 'interval', text : contador, 
                    editor: {xtype: 'textfield', flex: 0.5, editable: true}});
                grid.insert(gridView.columns.length, column);
                gridView.getView().refresh();
                var botao = Ext.getCmp('buttonRemoverColuna');
                botao.setDisabled(false);
            }
            contador++;
        }
    }


Ext.define('model', {
extend : 'Ext.data.Model',
fields : [ {
    name : 'id',
    type : 'long'
}, {
    name : 'name',
    type : 'string'
}, {
    name: 'interval',
    type: 'array'
}]
});
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by `data do not reply` in the question or `do not reply data` in your title, please try to rephrase this.

Comment: When I insert data on first grid's cell (1) the others cell repeat the data that I inserted, do you understand ??

Comment: Yes, I think I understand now. You are inserting a new column and it keeps the same data as the other columns.

Comment: The user can add columns dinamically, and then insert the data, but if him add data in one of column, data repeat for the all other columns, because has the same dataIndex.

Comment: After posting my answer I went through your question more and I think I understand it a bit better. I'm not sure if that answer was what you were looking for. You say that the model field is `type: array` but [**ExtJS doesn't have an array type**](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/3-4/#!/api/Ext.data.Field-cfg-type). Are you creating a [**custom type**](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/3-4/#!/api/Ext.data.Types)?

Comment: Hum, No, I'm not, I'm a beginner in Ext Js, in my back end application, there are one class which has a attribute that is a Array List (Java), how can I represent it in Ext Js model ??

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14646/discussion-between-geronimo-and-danilo-m)

Comment: Did you manage to do it?

Comment: Sorry some more priority things came in (real work), I added the example now.

Comment: It works !! Thank very much, I just made a little correction. In renderer I put `return intervals[intervalIndex - 1]`, because when I added data on second column, it was appearing on previous column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simple answer is that you have to give each new column that you insert a different `dataIndex` config.

Right now every one gets `dataIndex: 'interval'`.

That means if you put a value in the `interval` field in your store for that record, every single column that is connected to the `interval` field will show up with that value.

A simple way to do that would be to change the handler to this:

```
handler : function() {  
    var gridView = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('gridpanel')[1],
        grid = gridView.headerCt,
        columnCount = grid.getGridColumns().length;

    if (columnCount >= 1){
        var column = Ext.create('Ext.grid.column.Column', { 
                dataIndex: 'interval' + columnCount, 
                text: contador, 
                editor: {xtype: 'textfield', flex: 0.5, editable: true}
            });

        grid.insert(gridView.columns.length, column);
        gridView.getView().refresh();
        var botao = Ext.getCmp('buttonRemoverColuna');
        botao.setDisabled(false);
    }
    contador++;
}
```

Specifically, the following config from the handler will give it an incremented `dataIndex`, i.e. `interval1`, `interval2`, `interval3`, `interval4`, etc. I don't know anything about your server side set-up so I don't know if it will work for you:

```
dataIndex: 'interval' + columnCount,
```

**EDIT:**

Assuming you are not defining a custom `array` data type, your `interval` field data type will actually default to `string`. It will be easy to accomplish what you want using the grid column's `renderer` config, I'll post an example in a moment but you may as well change the data type back to `string`.

**EXAMPLE:**

The basic idea is to add a renderer to the column config that will show the individual `interval` values in the added columns by splitting the real `interval` field value into an array. You will still need an implementation of the grid columns with seperate `dataIndex` configs as shown above so that we can identify what columns match up to what `interval` array value.

```
handler : function() {  
    var grid = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('gridpanel')[1],
        header = grid.headerCt,
        intervalIndex = header.getGridColumns().length - 1;

    if (intervalIndex >= 0){
        var column = Ext.create('Ext.grid.column.Column', { 
                dataIndex: 'interval' + intervalIndex, 
                text: contador, 
                editor: {
                    xtype: 'textfield', 
                    intervalIndex: intervalIndex,
                    flex: 0.5, 
                    editable: true
                },

                // this will make the values display properly when not editing
                renderer: function(value, meta, record) {
                    var intervals = record.get('interval').split(',');
                    return intervals[intervalIndex];
                }
            });

        grid.insert(gridView.columns.length, column);
        gridView.getView().refresh();
        var botao = Ext.getCmp('buttonRemoverColuna');
        botao.setDisabled(false);
    }
    contador++;
}
```

You will also need `beforeedit` and `edit` event listeners on the grid.

The `beforeedit` handler will split the `interval` values into the correct column fields when you *start* a row edit.

The `edit` handler will join the updated field values from the different columns into a single string and apply it to the real `interval` field when you *complete* a row edit.

```
Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    // your other grid configs...
    listeners: {

        // this will make the values display properly when you start a row edit
        beforeedit: function(plugin, edit) {
            plugin.editor.items.each(function(field) {
                var idx = field.intervalIndex;
                if (idx) {
                    var value = edit.record.get('interval').split(',')[idx];
                    Ext.defer(function() {
                        field.setValue(value);
                    }, 10);
                }
            });
        },

        // update the value of the real "interval" field when done editing
        edit: function(plugin, edit) {
            var intervalArray = [],
                var regex = /interval\d/;

            Ext.Object.each(edit.newValues, function(key, value) {
                if (regex.test(key)) {
                    intervalArray.push(value);
                }
            });

            // sets the interval value into a comma seperated value string
            edit.record.set('interval', intervalArray.join(','));
        }
    }
});
```

With the above `edit` listener, the value of your model's `interval` field will be updated with the values in your added columns as a CSV string e.g.: `'value1,value2,value3,etc'`.

Parsing the string on your server side is up to you. But in most programming language there is a `stringValue.split(",")` type of function which will convert the CSV string into a real array.

If you wanted the `interval` value to be more "array-like" you could also wrap it in brackets:

```
edit.record.set('interval', '[' + intervalArray.join(',') + ']')
```

I don't know if that would help your parsing or not.

Comment: I understand, but in my model there are not field named 'interval1' or 'interval2', for example, so the data inserted will not appear in cell.

Comment: Ok, I am going to change the field now.